Why is there space for the hidden checkboxes with newer AgGrid?
We've recently upgraded to v30.2. Our rows have a visible checkbox in the first column but not in the other columns.
With the old version of ag-grid there was no space allowed for the hidden checkboxes, the text was displayed right on the left-hand side of the column.
With v30.2 there is a space allowed for the checkbox even though it is hidden. This means the text is now offset from the left hand edge of the column which looks kind of odd.
Is there a way with v30.2 to get the old behaviour, i.e. when checkbox is hidden text appears right up against left hand edge?
This is the generated HTML:
<div class="ag-cell-wrapper" role="presentation">
  <div class="ag-selection-checkbox ag-invisible" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true">
    <!--AG-CHECKBOX--><div role="presentation" ref="eCheckbox" class="ag-labeled ag-label-align-right ag-checkbox ag-input-field">
    <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-input-field-label ag-label ag-hidden ag-checkbox-label" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"></div>
    <div ref="eWrapper" class="ag-wrapper ag-input-wrapper ag-checkbox-input-wrapper" role="presentation">
      <input ref="eInput" class="ag-input-field-input ag-checkbox-input" type="checkbox" id="ag-86-input" tabindex="-1" aria-live="polite" aria-label="Press Space to toggle row selection (unchecked)">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <span class="ag-cell-value" role="presentation">Some text</span>
</div>

With the old AgGrid, ag-hidden was used instead of ag-invisible. If I edit HTML in browser to replace ag-invisible with ag-hidden, then I get the layout I want, as it used to be.
There is a load of code scattered throughout our application and the person who wrote it is no longer with the company, so I don't know what will help. This is the grid options:
const gridOptions = {
    /* Custom components */
    components: {
        loadingCellRenderer: LoadingCellRenderer,
    },
    columnDefs: null,
    // Default column props - overridden by column type props or specific column props
    defaultColDef: {
        flex: 1,
        resizable: true,
        checkboxSelection: isFirstColumn,  // always display selection checkbox in first visible column (L-R) of grid
        // Render cells with loading spinner if their row (node) contents are not loaded,
        // else use default rendering for the cell value
        // see https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/angular/cell-rendering/#provided-cell-renderers
        cellRendererSelector: function(params) {
            if (params.node.id === undefined && isFirstColumn(params)) {
                return {component: 'loadingCellRenderer'};
            }
            // Use default renderer (renders value as a string)
            return null;
        }
    },
    // Set default props for columns of specified type (overridden by specific column props)
    columnTypes: {
        textDataColumn: {
            filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
            filterParams: {
                buttons: ['reset', 'apply'],
                closeOnApply: true,
                caseSensitive: true,
                filterOptions: ['equals', 'notEqual', 'startsWith'],
            },
        },
        numDataColumn: {
            filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
            filterParams: {
                buttons: ['reset', 'apply'],
                closeOnApply: true,
                filterOptions: ['equals', 'notEqual', 'lessThan', 'lessThanOrEqual', 'greaterThan', 'greaterThanOrEqual'],
            },
            headerClass: 'ag-right-aligned-header',
            cellClass: 'ag-right-aligned-cell',
        },
        textFilterColumn: {
            filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
            filterParams: {
                buttons: ['reset', 'apply'],
                closeOnApply: true,
                caseSensitive: true,
                filterOptions: [
                    // Built in filter options
                    'contains',
                    'notContains',
                    // Custom filter options
                    {displayKey: 'matchesRegexp', displayName: 'Matches regexp', test: true},
                    {displayKey: 'notMatchesRegexp', displayName: 'Not matches regexp', test: true},
                    {displayKey: 'iContains', displayName: 'Contains (case insensitive)', test: true},
                    {displayKey: 'iNotContains', displayName: 'Not contains (case insensitive)', test: true},
                ],
                defaultOption: 'contains',
                suppressAndOrCondition: false,  // allow selection of two filtering conditions
            },
        },
        timeRefColumn: {
            filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
            filterParams: {
                buttons: ['reset', 'apply'],
                closeOnApply: true,
                filterOptions: ['equals', 'notEqual', 'lessThan', 'lessThanOrEqual', 'greaterThan', 'greaterThanOrEqual'],
            },
            headerClass: 'ag-right-aligned-header',
            cellClass: 'ag-right-aligned-cell',
        },
        rightAlignColumn: {
            headerClass: 'ag-right-aligned-header',
            cellClass: 'ag-right-aligned-cell',
        },
    },
    context: {
        filename: null
    },
    rowData: null,
    // infinite row model
    rowModelType: 'infinite',
    maxBlocksInCache: 4,
    cacheBlockSize: 800,
    blockLoadDebounceMillis: 100,  // wait for scrolling to stop for this many ms before loading block
    // how many rows to allow scrolling beyond loaded rows
    cacheOverflowSize: 1,
    // allow multiple rows to be selected at a time
    rowSelection: 'multiple',
    // use check box for row selection (reserve clicking on rows for linked timeline event selection)
    suppressRowClickSelection: true,
    // stop columns being removed if they are dragged outside of the grid e.g. during rearranging columns
    suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns: true,
    // allow copy-pasting of row content
    enableCellTextSelection: true,
    ensureDomOrder: true,
    // suppress sorting by multiple columns with shift+click for now as not really useful when only sorting by
    // signal ID and timestamp
    suppressMultiSort: true,
};



Can you please provide the basic sample code as a reference? thanks.
